# How can I get specific fields (which need to be joined) into a single row per entry

Tags: mysql

If you are familiar with OSTicket, that's the database I'm working with.

I am trying to get the following information per row (I am not using the actual field names in this for readabilities sake, but I am keeping it consistent)

```
ticket_id, ticket_number, custom_field_1_value, custom_field_2_value
```

> form_entry_values (contains: entry_id, custom_field_number, custom_field_value)
>
> form_entry (contains: entry_id, ticket_id)
>
> field (contains: field_id)
>
> ticket (contains: ticket_id, ticket_number)

I'm able to easily (with two joins) get ONE field like so

```
SELECT t.ticket_id,
    t.ticket_number,
    v.custom_field_value
FROM ticket t
LEFT JOIN form_entry e
    ON e.ticket_id = t.ticket_id
LEFT JOIN form_entry_values v
    ON v.entry_id = e.entry_id
WHERE v.custom_field_number = 1
```

I can't figure out how to do it for the two fields I want, but still get it on a single row per ticket_id.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are very close. Because you want to get other records from that `form_entry_values` table for the ticket, you'll need to join that many times to it. Each time, you can specify the custom_field_number in the `ON` part of the join so your WHERE doesn't get all gnarly.

```
SELECT t.ticket_id,
    t.ticket_number,
    v1.custom_field_value
    v2.custom_field_value
FROM ticket t
LEFT JOIN form_entry e
    ON e.ticket_id = t.ticket_id
LEFT JOIN form_entry_values v1
    ON v1.entry_id = e.entry_id
    AND v1.custom_field_number = 1
LEFT JOIN form_entry_values v1
    ON v2.entry_id = e.entry_id
    AND v2.custom_field_number = 2
```

Comment: This works, though I had to use MAX on the v1 and v2.custom_field_values to get them to ultimately group correctly